# Can we connect ejabberd to xampp mysql server?

Tags: ejabberd

By default, ejabberd uses Mnesia, but has support for odbc database as well. So, can I use XAMPP MySQL database for ejabberd?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Follow the steps described in this [link](http://www.ejabberd.im/Using%20ejabberd%20with%20MySQL%20native%20driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use mysql instead of mnesia in most cases. To use mysql, reconfigure module section in ejabberd.cfg and configure mysql section.

Ejabberd is very modular system, so components are independent (session, roster, muc, etc...). If there is odbc version of some mod you can easily switch to odbc. If there is not, you can implement it.

To conclude, however, I would not recommend xampp which may cause security issues. Simply install vanilla mysql and work on it.